# Выбор метода в зависимости от ОС

Tags: python, ооп, классы, наследование

У меня есть класс, в котором есть публичный метод specInput(), который использует приватный метод __setcoolor(*args). Но проблема в том, что на шиндовс и на линукс этот метод выглядит немного по другому. Я думаю сделать отдельные файлы с методами в папке рядом и, в зависимости от ОС, выбрать один из них и перезаписать стандартный публичный метод в классе, чтоб приватный метод в нем работал. Думаю в коде будет понятнее:

```
#mainclass.py
class Mainclass:
  def __init__(self, os):
    if os == "linux":
       #...
    elif os == "win32":
       #...
    #...
  def __setcolor(self):
    #...
  def specInput(self)
    self.__setcolor()
    print("default")
    #...

#platforms/win32.py
class Win32:
  def specInput(self)
    self.__setcolor()
    print("win32")
    #...
  
#platforms/linux.py
class linux:
  def specInput(self)
    self.__setcolor()
    print("linux")
    #...
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну что-то типа такого, если я правильно понял что нужно

```py
def __setcolor(self):
    import platform
    if (system := platform.system()) == 'Windows':
        print('Windows')
    elif system == 'Linux':
        print('Linux')
```

##### UPD по коментарию

Фигня конечно, но попробуйте так
`obj.py`

```py
import platform


class LinClass:
    def __init__(self):
        ...

    def __set_color(self):
        ...


class WinClass(LinClass):
    def __set_color(self):
        ...


if platform.system() == 'Windows':
    MainClass = WinClass
else:
    MainClass = LinClass
```

`main.py`

```py
from obj import MainClass

c = MainClass()
```

Comment: Не то, мне нужно перезаписать метод specInput() в классе, чтобы постоянно не использовать if при вызове метода, а сделать это в самом начале кода.

Comment: @Льоха, дополнил ответ. Посмотрите, может подойдет

Answer (score 0):

Ну, так просто берёте и перезаписываете:

```
class Mainclass:
  def __init__(self, os):
    if os == "linux":
       self.specInput = linux.specInput
    elif os == "win32":
       self.specInput = Win32.specInput
```

Хотя на самом деле, из вашего примера вообще не очень понятно, зачем отдельные классы linux и Win32 - можно просто без всяких классов сделать пару функций, и потом перезаписывать ими метод.